# ServiceStack #Script Argument in Database Script

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have the following #Script (ServiceStack framework) template.
I want to use the argument Code in my dbSelect.
How is this possible?

Example:

```
<small>Some Label</small><header>{{Code}}</header>
{{ 'select * from TrackingEntity WHERE Barcode = @Barcode' |> to => selectSql }}
{{ selectSql |> dbSelect({Barcode: {Code} }) |> htmlDump({ className: 'table styled-table' }) }}
```

In this line of code, I am trying to pass the argument to the dbSelect function.

**selectSql** |> dbSelect({Barcode: **{Code}** })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dbSelect` accepts a JS object literal, try:

```
selectSql |> dbSelect({ Barcode: Code })
```